# Cassandra Ec2MultiRegionSnitch or GossipingPropertyFileSnitch for AWS regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, datastax

We have 3 Cassandra nodes in U.S. AWS region and 3 nodes in Singapore AWS region. If I have to build a multi-data center is it mandatory for us to use Ec2MultiRegionSnitch?  Or can we use the GossipingPropertyFileSnitch?

And should I use only private IP addresses for the both broadcast addresses and listen address here?

As my system administrator told me, we don't need public IP for these and private IP should work as both can communicate with each other.  But I am doubtful of that.  Can someone kindly shed some light on this?

Comment: Consider editing you question, mentioning Cassandra explicitly. You don't mention it on title neither on body.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason for you not to use the *Ec2MultiRegionSnitch* snitching method, if you intend to use *NetworkTopologyStrategy* for you keyspace (which makes Cassandra datacenter aware). Otherwise, you would have to configure your topology manually, like below:

> In EC2 deployments, the region name is treated as the data center name and availability zones are treated as racks within a data center. For example, if a node is in the us-east-1 region, us-east is the data center name and 1 is the rack location.

So, using it, Cassandra will automatically get that information from [instances' metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html).

As for public IPs, you do need them, because you can't establish peering between VPCs across regions, so instances can't communicate with each other inside those VPCs.

Again, [Datastax's documention](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureSnitchEC2MultiRegion_c.html) says how to do that:

> In the cassandra.yaml, set the listen_address to the private IP address of the node, and the broadcast_address to the public IP address of the node.

Comment: oh.. does that mean i can assing replication factor using the region name here while creating keyspaces? and when i enter nodetool status it will show the single data center instead of region names as dc. that is what i am concerned about.

Comment: I never used it, but, yes, I would expect to use region names when creating namespaces and assigning replication factors. Nodetool status should show region names on DC row. Actually, like the documentation says, regions are equivalent to DCs and AZs to racks.

Comment: I have gone through few datastax documents and the scenario you said is possible only if we use EC2snitch. I tried gossippropertyfilesnitch and used us 3 nodes and singapore 3 nodes and when entered nodetool status it only shows one data center( the name i used in rackdc-properties file).  EC2snitch only might make the difference here. Would like to hear comments from you or others.