# Migrating from Ec2Snitch to Ec2MultiRegionSnitch

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I currently have a 5 node cassandra cluster running with Ec2Snitch in us-west-2.

I want to add a second datacenter in us-west-1, so I need to use Ec2MultiRegionSnitch instead.

How should I go about doing this?

On a test deployment, I tried setting all broadcast_addresses to public ip, changing the snitch, and using public ips for the seeds.

After doing this, when running nodetool from a node, I only see `UN` for that node, and `DN` for all the other nodes, who are only reporting their private ip address.

Comment: Here is a question/answer that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789711/ec2multiregionsnitch-or-gossipingpropertyfilesnitch-for-aws-regions

Comment: Unfortunately it is not helpful. I have already done the suggested steps:

setting broadcast_address to my public ip and listen_address to my private ip. However, the nodes do not appear to see each other.

Comment: @dacox - has this been resolved?